# What parts of a HTTP POST web request need to be URL Encoded?

Tags: http, encoding, webrequest

I have been browsing for an answer, but I am a bit confused about which parts of POST data need to be URL encoded. I am submitting an HTTP post request with name/value parameters, and content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Do I need to build my entire parameter string ie)
    encode(postData)
or and then encode each name/value pair separately?
    encode(paramName) + "=" + encode(paramValue) + "&"

From Chrome developer tools the raw request I'm trying to replicate looks like option 2, but what I've read online seems to indicate option 1.

Thanks

Comment: how are you building this request? Normally you shouldn't have to be building the request body yourself, just provide a key=value array/list/whatever to the underlying language's http library and let it do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) and [Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

> Control names and values are escaped

So, option 2.

Comment: Quick and precise answer, thanks! The W3 document is where I should have gone first. The second part: Control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document, is good to know too!